# How to create dummy variables for interaction term between categorical variables?

Tags: categorical-data, interaction, contrasts

I'm building a logistic regression model estimating the probability of hospitalization based on several predictor variables, including indicator variables for various diagnosis categories (coded as Yes=1, No=0) and types of medication (coded as Yes=1, No=0).

I've included an interaction term for several diagnosis & medication categories, for example (Major_depression)*(Antidepressant), to estimate the odds ratio of hospitalization among patients suffering an illness who take proper medication vs. those who do not take proper medication.

As it is, including the term Major_depression x Antidepressant in the model makes a blanket comparison of those who suffer major depression and take medication (Major_depression x Antidepressant = 1 x 1 = 1) vs. all other combinations (Major_depression x Antidepressant = 1 x 0 = 0, or = 0 x 1 = 0, or = 0 x 0 = 0).

How do I create a variable specifically comparing those suffering depression who **do** take medication vs. those suffering depression who **do not** take medication while ignoring the less interesting cases of people who are not depressed?

Would this be the correct contrast coding?

x1 = 1 if Major_depression = 1 and Antidepressant = 1,

x1 = 0 if Major_depression = 0 and Antidepressant = 1,

x1 = 0 if Major_depression = 0 and Antidepressant = 0,

x1 = -1 if Major_depression = 1 and Antidepressant = 0.